# Slim v3 PUT method and retrieve POST data

Tags: post, slim, put

I have added route to update emails in a database which uses PUT method

`$app->put('/notifications/{email}', 'add_email_address');`

and function for it looks like:

```
function add_email_address($request, $response, $args) {

  $email = $args['email'];
  $addon_email = $request->getParam('addon_email', null);

  echo "ADD/UPDATE $email with $addon_email";

}
```

**UPDATE** somehow on testing PUT method with a form input post `addon_email = test@null.com`  retrieved value for `$addon_email` is empty;

Any tips what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it to work by changing

`$addon_email = $app->request->getParam('addon_email', null);`

to

```
$allPostPutVars = $request->getParsedBody();
$addon_email = $allPostPutVars['addon_email'];
```

It looks like `getParam` works only for GET method. Also content-type must be set as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$request->getParams()` to get array of all `POST`/`PUT` parameters, or you can use `$reqeuest->getParam('key', 'defaultValue')`, where `'key'` is paramter name and `'defaultValue'` is... well, default value in case parameter is missing.

So,

```
function add_email_address($request, $response, $args) {

  $email = $args['email'];
  $addon_email = $app->request->getParam('addon_email', null);

  // some code....

  return $response->withJson("ADD/UPDATE $email with $email");

}
```

**EDIT**

We both forgot that you should return response object. )

Since `add_email_address` is route callback, it should return `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` response.

Comment: Still Error 500 but this time on `use ($app)` declaration. I have removed `use ($app)` and `$addon_email = $app->request->getParam('addon_email', null);` still gives 500

Comment: I have updated OP as it looks like I have mixed an old code from v2 which no longer works on v3. Now I'm getting 200 OK but no post value.

Comment: Do you have `displayErrorDetails` set to `true` in your config? In case you have not, [here is how you do it](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html).

Comment: I have added it - still no clue why `addon_email` is processed as empty